# Why is the site called twice?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

When I set on page-

```
@page "{categoryname}"
```

This causes the page to be call twice.
The first time the categoryname uses an entry written on the address page.
But on the second turn he calls **categoryname="checkout"** (I do not know if it is related to that, but on the same page there is AJAX calling the page by the above name- "checkout").

When I delete - @page "{categoryname}" it works fine and call just 1 time!

And I tried to change the name of the categoryname to another name ( i thought maybe there is another place called like that, but I saw that it also changed the name and has the same problem.)

What can I do?

Best regards

**EDIT**

this is the page code-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title> @ViewData["Title"] </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/js/ckeditor5-build-classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5212bc06e1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

</head>
<body>

    @using OrdersCore.Interfaces

    @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

    @inject HomeServices Customer

    @{



        var currentCust = new Models.Customer();

        foreach (var cookie in HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
        {
            if (cookie.Key == "OrderLoginDetails")
            {
                if (Customer.GetCustomer(cookie.Value) != null)
                {
                    Customer.Cookie = cookie.Value;
                }
            }

        }
        if (Customer.Cookie == null)
        {



        }
    }





    <header style="position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: 0;z-index:99">
        <div class="menuUp">

            <div class="container flexMenu whiteLinks">
                <div class="justMobile">
                    <a href="/index">
                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="justMobile">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                        <div class="nonMobile">
                            <label class="dropbtn">
                                @if (@Customer.GetProductsInCart(Customer.Cookie) != null)
                                {
                                    int countProd = 0;
                                    @foreach (var item in Customer.GetProductsInCart(Customer.Cookie))
                                    {
                                        countProd += item.Quantity;
                                    }


                                    <span id="QuantityProds">
                                        @Html.Raw(countProd)
                                    </span>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span id="QuantityProds">0</span>
                                }
                                מוצרים בסל

                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">

                            <span id="txtHint"></span>

                            <div class="btnInsertToCart" style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:0;padding:5px; width: auto;">
                                <a asp-page="checkout">תשלום</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>


                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                        <div class="nonMobile">

                            <label class="dropbtn">
                                החשבון שלי
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="dropdown-content">

                            <span id="spanConnecting"></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="justMobile">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="nonMobile">

                    ראשי      |    אודותינו     |    צרו קשר
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menuMiddle">
            <div class="container flexMenu">
                <div>
                    <a asp-page="./index">
                        <img src="~/Images/logo.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="nonMobile">
                    <form class="search" method="get" asp-page="/search">
                        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="חיפוש.." class="quantity" name="SearchString">
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark menuBottom border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-lg-start">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        @foreach (var item in Customer.GetNav(0))
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    @item.TagsName
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                                    @foreach (var item2 in Customer.GetNav(item.Id))
                                    {

                                        <a asp-page="Category" asp-route-categoryName="@item2.TagsName" class="dropdown-item">@item2.TagsName</a>


                                    }
                                </div>
                            </li>

                        }

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>






    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - OrdersCore - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.productPrice').each(function () {
                var new_text = parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2);
                $(this).text(new_text + " ₪");
            })

            $('.productDetails').each(function () {
                var new_text2 = $(this).text().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
                new_text2 = new_text2.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
                $(this).text(new_text2);
            })



        });
    </script>

    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#connecting").load("Connecting");
        });

    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.cartPrice').each(function () {
                var new_text = parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2);
                $(this).text(new_text + " ₪");
            })
        });



    </script>
    <script>
        $('#txtHint').load('Checkout #cartProducts', function (data) {
            var $script = $(data).find('span[id=script]');
            if ($script.length) {
                $.getScript($script.html());
                // remove the span tag -- no need to render it
                $script.remove();
            }
            $('Checkout #cartProducts').html(data);
        })
        $('#spanConnecting').load('connecting', function (data) {
            var $script = $(data).find('span[id=script]');
            if ($script.length) {
                $.getScript($script.html());
                // remove the span tag -- no need to render it
                $script.remove();
            }
            $('connecting').html(data);
        });



        function changeCart() {
            $('#txtHint').load('Checkout #cartProducts', function (data) {
                var $script = $(data).find('span[id=script]');
                if ($script.length) {
                    $.getScript($script.html());
                    // remove the span tag -- no need to render it
                    $script.remove();
                }
                $('Checkout #cartProducts').html(data);


                $('#QuantityProds').each(function () {
                    var new_text = parseFloat($(this).text()) + 1;
                    $(this).text(new_text);
                })
            });
        };
    </script>
    <script>

        function deleteCart(form, quant, price) {

            sum = $(form).parents('tr').find('*').text();
            $(form).parents('tr').remove();

            $('#QuantityProds').each(function () {
                var new_text = parseFloat($(this).text()) - parseFloat(quant);
                $(this).text(new_text);
            })

            var newPrice = parseFloat($("#cartPrice").text().replace("₪", ""));
            newPrice = newPrice - price;
            console.log(newPrice)
            $("#cartPrice").text(newPrice);


        };


    </script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should add some more detail - show the code you have, explain what you want it to do, and how it actually behaves.

Comment: Do you mean when you use @page "{categoryname}",and when you call it,you will get a  right call at the first time,and you will always get categoryname="checkout" at the second time?If so,I think maybe you will always call the ajax when page load,where you put the ajax?In `$(function(){})` or `window.onload = function() {}`?You need to show the page with @page "{categoryname}".

Comment: I put the ajax in $(document).ready(function ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This causes the page to be call twice." is because you put ajax in `$(document).ready(function ()`.

Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will run once when the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.First call is your call,and the second call is by the ajax in `$(document).ready()`.

Solution is removing the ajax from `$( document ).ready()`.

Comment: That does not solve the problem. I edited the question and added all the code